# Magento 2 add base price to each customisable option

Tags: magento2, radix, price

We have a magento 2 site and we have setup a simple product. The base price of the product is $5.00.
We have added a couple of Customizable Options. Please see screenshot here: https://www.screencast.com/t/91jD8zp0
Now on the front end, it calculates the price correctly if only one of the dropdown is seleted.

https://www.screencast.com/t/s2bh7sgI9
https://www.screencast.com/t/1l341A4WSm

But if you select options from both dropdowns, Magento adds the base price to only one of the dropdowns and that's why final price is not correct. Can someone please advise how we can force Magento to add base price on each selection.

We have tried that with fixed pricing as well but same results.